# Arduino - Parsing GET String

Tags: arduino

Hate to post this, but I am googled out and tried many different options with no success.

Basically I would like to GET a page with the status of 10 lights and turn on/off the corresponding lights. The Arduino is getting the results and posting the string in the serial monitor, but the string is not triggering my if statements. Not sure if I am using the wrong function to parse the string or my if statements are incorrect.

Here is the output of the GET, which posts in the serial monitor (printing `readString`):

> Light1:1
>   Light2:0
>   Light3:0
>   Light4:0
>   Light5:0
>   Light6:1
>   Light7:0
>   Light8:1
>   Light9:0
>   Light10:0

Here is the last thing I tried in the sketch, with an if statement for each light:

```cpp
if (readString.indexOf("Light1:1">0)) 
{
    digitalWrite(light1, HIGH);
}
else
{ 
    digitalWrite(light1, LOW);  
}
```

What function would you use? What am I doing wrong?
Restructuring the output of the page is also an option.

Comment: Seems like an easier format would just be 10 1s or 0s all in a row...that's easier to parse (but less flexible or extensible).

Comment: I tried changing the output to just 1s and 0s. Seems more efficient and flexibility isn't an issue here. I used readString.substring(1,1) == "1" for each position, still no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible typo... you've got your comparison inside the `.indexOf()` call. Did you mean

```
if (readString.indexOf("Light1:1") >= 0)
```

Comment: Yahtzee! :-) You were correct my indexOf statement was not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The string will start at position 0. Use >= 0

Comment: and you'll get a value of -1 if not found.

Comment: Tried the solution, still no luck.